# Fetch value based in that same JSON key value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the JSON like

```
var resultJSON = `{
  "data": {
    "total": 1,
    "list_name": "title",
    "title": {
      "id": 53,
      "name": "Sonu",
      "mobileNo": "6543213456",
      "address": "Greeny Pathway",
      "city": "NewYork",
      "mode": "Weekly",
      "duration": "15",
      "qty": null
    },
    "download": [{
      "time": "16789042",
      "date": "26 - 01 - 2020"
    }]
  }
}`;
```

I expect the output:

```
{
  "total": "1",
  "list_name": "title",
  "name": "sonu",
  "mobileno": "6543213456"
}
```

Here `"list_name": "title"` is dynamic, sometimes it will come `"list_name": "book"`, based on that above mentioned response I want to get.

Comment: Consider `JSON.parse`? (That's actual JSON for once)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I had to fix your invalid JSON

You can make it more clever if you study https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment in depth

```js
const resultJSON = `{
  "data": {
    "total": 1,
    "list_name": "title",
    "title": {
      "id": 53,
      "name": "Sonu",
      "mobileNo": "6543213456",
      "address": "Greeny Pathway",
      "city": "NewYork",
      "mode": "Weekly",
      "duration": "15",
      "qty": null
    },
    "download": [{
      "time": "16789042",
      "date": "26-01-2020"
    }]
  }
}`
const data = JSON.parse(resultJSON).data
const content = data[data.list_name];
let newObj = {} 

newObj["total"]     = data["total"];
newObj["list_name"] = data["list_name"];
newObj["name"]      = content["name"];
newObj["mobileNo"]  = content["mobileNo"];
console.log(newObj)
```